# EF Core: I end up with duplicates in database when importing records with json.net

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, json.net, entity-framework-core

I will start with the code that causes trouble just in case there is something super obvious that I am missing:

```
foreach(JToken OrgToken in json["Orgs"]) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Org " + OrgToken["Name"]);
    Org o = OrgToken.ToObject < Org > ();
    _cont.Orgs.Add(o);
    _influxClient.CreateDatabaseAsync(o.MetricDatabaseName);

    foreach(JToken PortfolioToken in OrgToken["Portfolios"]) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Portfolio " + PortfolioToken["Name"]);
        Portfolio p = PortfolioToken.ToObject < Portfolio > ();
        p.OrganizationId = o.Id;
        _cont.Portfolios.Add(p);

        foreach(JObject ProjectToken in PortfolioToken["Projects"]) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Project " + ProjectToken["Name"]);
            Project prj = ProjectToken.ToObject < Project > ();
            prj.PortfolioId = p.Id;
            _cont.Projects.Add(prj);
            _cont.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
_cont.SaveChanges();
```

This code will load a hierarchy of related objects (Org->Portfolio->Project) from a JSON file:

```
{
  "Orgs": [
    {
      "Name": "StrongSoft",
      "Users": [
        {
          "email": "StrongSoftAdmin@clevereer.com",
          "password": "password",
          "IsOrgAdmin": true
        },
        {
          "email": "StrongSoftReadOnly@clevereer.com",
          "password": "password",
          "IsOrgAdmin": false
        }
      ],
      "Portfolios": [
        {
          "Name": "Financial",
          "Projects": [
            { "Name": "Derivatives Trading" },
            { "Name": "Fixed Income" },
            { "Name": "Fix Market Connector" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "Machinery",
          "Projects": [
            { "Name": "Hard Metal Stuff" },
            { "Name": "Health Management Framework" },
            { "Name": "Look and Poock" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "Lab",
          "Projects": [
            { "Name": "!@#$%^&*()_+++++++++w+" },
            { "Name": "Какое-то странное имя, это капец" },
            { "Name": "" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Clevereer",
      "Users": [
        {
          "email": "ClevereerAdmin@clevereer.com",
          "password": "password",
          "IsOrgAdmin": true
        },
        {
          "email": "ClevereerReadOnly@clevereer.com",
          "password": "password",
          "IsOrgAdmin": false
        }
      ],
      "Portfolios": [
        {
          "Name": "Prospects",
          "Projects": [
            { "Name": "AI Assisted Surveillance" },
            { "Name": "Metrics Keeper" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that when this runs, I end up having 2 duplicates for each of the `Portfolio` objects and 3 duplicates for each of the `Project`. `Org` comes with no duplicates.

I have made sure that the loops make proper number of "stops" and the objects are only attempted to be created once (hence the `Debug.WriteLine()`):

```
Org StrongSoft
Portfolio Financial
Project Derivatives Trading
Project Fixed Income
Project Fix Market Connector
Portfolio Machinery
Project Hard Metal Stuff
Project Health Management Framework
Project Look and Poock
Portfolio Lab
Project !@#$%^&*()_+++++++++w+
Project Какое-то странное имя, это капец
Project 
Org Clevereer
Portfolio Prospects
Project AI Assisted Surveillance
Project Metrics Keeper
```

I tried `SaveChanges()` and `Attach()` routines

I tried altering `EntityState` of added objects so that EF does not assume they are changed and tries to re-create them

Nothing is working out for me.

I suspect the roots of the problem are in the relationships but I only refer/set to the `Id` fields (this does not seem to trigger population of the `Navigation Property` of the related model - why is this causing a problem?) What I don't know if I am not saving the objects correctly or it's the entities design that isn't right. When I save entities (including defining their relationships) via controllers the duplication does not occur.

The entities and their relationships are fairly straightforward:

```
public class Org : BaseEntity, IEntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }

    }

public class Portfolio : BaseEntity, IEntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
        public virtual Org Organization { get; set; }

        public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
        public List<Project> Projects {get;set;}
    }
}

public class Project : BaseEntity, IEntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int PortfolioId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PortfolioId")]
        public Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update:** I tried various things to get this fixed, including:

calling `_cont.SaveChanges()` every time an object is added to dbSet:

```
Org o = OrgToken.ToObject<Org>();
_cont.Orgs.Add(o);
_cont.SaveChanges();
```

Retrieving a saved object from the database to create the relationship:

```
Portfolio p = PortfolioToken.ToObject<Portfolio>();
p.OrganizationId = _cont.Orgs.Find(o.Id).Id;
_cont.Portfolios.Add(p);
_cont.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
Portfolio p = PortfolioToken.ToObject<Portfolio>();
p.Organization = _cont.Orgs.Find(o.Id);
_cont.Portfolios.Add(p);
_cont.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
Portfolio p = PortfolioToken.ToObject<Portfolio>();
p.Organization = _cont.Find<Org>(p.id);
_cont.Portfolios.Add(p);
_cont.SaveChanges();
```

My Context is nothing fancy, I don't think there is anything that could impact it:

```
public class CoreContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Org> Orgs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Metric> Metrics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrgAccess> OrgAccess { get; set; }

    public CoreContext(DbContextOptions<CoreContext> options) : base(options) { } 
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
            {
                relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
            }

            modelBuilder.Entity<Org>().ToTable("Org").HasIndex(c=>c.Name).IsUnique();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Portfolio>().ToTable("Portfolio").HasOne(a => a.Organization);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its  State Management of the graphs, since it doesn't know how to handle the insertions of the Org(s), none of the Orgs actually get Id's till they are pushed to the database with a `SaveChanges()` which you never do in the first loop before jumping into the Portfolios, if there is an Id I would be surprised. Same thing with Portfolios to Projects I believe.

Comment: I tried saving changes as soon as an object is added - no cure

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the EntityFramework or the Context or the Database. The problem is with how Newtonsoft JSON mapper works. Not that it's a problem but it's totally unexpected that while converting a portion of the JSON file `.ToObject<T>()`, it will create underlying objects *(I assume)* if their name conversions match relationship between object classes. It did so for `Portfolio` and `Project` but didn't do this for the `Users` collection since there is no relationship between the models.

I wish it wasn't doing this so implicitly but it's what it is. I am sharing this just in case someone bumps into this trouble.

The resulting code would need to look like this:

```
public void CreateOrgStructure(string path = "/Test/TestData.json"){
        string DataFilePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory + path;
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(DataFilePath));
        foreach (JToken OrgToken in json["Orgs"])
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Org "+OrgToken["Name"]);
                Org o = OrgToken.ToObject<Org>();
                _cont.Orgs.Add(o);
                _cont.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```